# Where are the magic rules for GHC assert?

Tags: haskell, ghc, assertions

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#assert seems to define `assert` to be a no-op. Where's the logic that turns this into something else when assertions are enabled?

Comment: It's compiler magic same as `lazy` and `breakpoint`. Likely there's either a special case in GHC for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The comment above that function gives a hint:

```
-- Assertion function.  This simply ignores its boolean argument.
-- The compiler may rewrite it to @('assertError' line)@.
```

So, just use github code search and search for `assertError`: [search results](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/search?q=assertError&ref=cmdform)

This turns up the file [RnExpr.lhs](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/778b48afc36e2b0eb44387e2a36947ac0c6ddd95/compiler/rename/RnExpr.lhs). Searching for assert in this file, you'll find the following code:

```
finishHsVar :: Name -> RnM (HsExpr Name, FreeVars)
-- Separated from rnExpr because it's also used
-- when renaming infix expressions
-- See Note [Adding the implicit parameter to 'assert']
finishHsVar name
 = do { this_mod <- getModule
      ; when (nameIsLocalOrFrom this_mod name) $
        checkThLocalName name

      ; ignore_asserts <- goptM Opt_IgnoreAsserts
      ; if ignore_asserts || not (name `hasKey` assertIdKey)
        then return (HsVar name, unitFV name)
        else do { e <- mkAssertErrorExpr
                ; return (e, unitFV name) } }
```

That's where it replaces `assert` by `assertError`, but only if assertions are enabled.
`assertError` is defined in [GHC.IO.Exception](https://github.com/ghc/packages-base/blob/master/GHC/IO/Exception.hs#L339)

Comment: Interesting. Is there a reason this can't be handled more generically? I would think an explicit `RULE` pragma wrapped in preprocessor magic that tests for the GHC ignore-asserts option would be easier to follow.

Comment: @dfeuer That would be easier to follow, but ghc also rewrites assert to `assertError` + location information. A `RULE` pragma couldn't get this location information. I'm not even sure if a `RULE` pragma can check for GHC optimization flags.

Comment: I was suggesting that the `RULE` be conditionally compiled based on the flag. I don't know if that's possible either, but it's the sort of thing even CPP can manage in some contexts. Location information seems generally useful—why not a magical "location" function that expands to information about the location it appears in?